# Too many arguments for format string when using %d or .format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code like this, but I dont know where is the mistake

```
x = int(input())

hh = x // 3600
second = x % 3600
mm = second // 60
ss = second % 60

print("%d remaining seconds is equal to %d:%d:%d".format(x, hh, second, mm, ss))

#Output
%d remaining seconds in equal to %d:%d:%d < I dont know why this code still %d and didnt change into numbers
```

And when I use `print("%d remaining seconds is equal to %d:%d:%d" % (x, hh, second, mm, ss))` there will be the error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: See also this for the current approach to string formatting: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of format why not use an f-string, that will allow you to embed the variables directly in the string.

```
print(f"{x} remaining seconds is equal to {hh}:{second}:{mm}:{ss}")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change `print` line to this line

```py
print("{} remaining seconds is equal to {}:{}:{}:{}".format(x, hh, second, mm, ss))
```

or

```py
print("%d remaining seconds is equal to %d:%d:%d:%d" % (x, hh, second, mm, ss))
```